# Simplification of derivative of square using sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to use sympy to generate equations for non-linear least squares fitting. My goal is to make this quite complex but for the moment, here's a simple case (but not too simple!). It's basically fitting a two dimensional sinusoid to data. Here's the sympy code:

```
from sympy import *
S, l, m = symbols('S l m', real=True)
u, v = symbols('u v', real=True)
Vobs = symbols('Vobs', complex=True)
Vres = Vobs - S * exp(- 1j * 2 * pi * (u*l+v*m))
J=Vres*conjugate(Vres)
axes = [S, l, m]
grad = derive_by_array(J, axes)
hess = derive_by_array(grad, axes)
```

One element of the grad term looks like:

```
- 2.0*I*pi*S*u*(-S*exp(-2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)) + Vobs)*exp(2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)) + 2.0*I*pi*S*u*(-S*exp(2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)) + conjugate(Vobs))*exp(-2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v))
```

What I'd like is to replace the expanded term `(-S*exp(-2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)) + Vobs)` by Vres and contract the two conjugate terms into the more compact equivalent is:

```
4.0*pi*S*u*im(Vres*exp(2.0*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)))
```

I cannot see how to do this with sympy. This problem is bad for the first derivative (grad) but get really out of hand with the second derivative (hess).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's not use 1j in SymPy, it's a float and floats are bad for symbolic math. SymPy's imaginary unit is `I`. So,

```
Vres = Vobs - S * exp(- I * 2 * pi * (u*l+v*m))
```

To replace the expression Vres by a symbol, we first need to create such a symbol. I'm going to call it  `Vres0`, but its name will be Vres, so it prints as "Vres" in formulas.

```
Vres0 = symbols('Vres')
g1 = grad[1].subs(Vres, Vres0).conjugate().subs(Vres, Vres0).conjugate()
```

The conjugate-substitute-conjugate back is needed because `subs` doesn't quite recognize the possibility of replacing the conjugate of an expression with  the conjugate of the symbol.

Now g1 is

```
-2*I*pi*S*Vres*u*exp(2*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)) + 2*I*pi*S*u*exp(-2*I*pi*(l*u + m*v))*conjugate(Vres)
```

and we want to fold the sum of conjugate terms. I use a custom transformation rule for this: the rule `fold_conjugates` applies to every sum (`Add`) of two terms (`len(f.args) == 2`) where the second is a conjugate of the first (`f.args[1] == f.args[0].conjugate()`). The transformation it performs: replace the sum by twice the real part of first argument (`2*re(f.args[0])`). Like so:

```
from sympy.core.rules import Transform
fold_conjugates = Transform(lambda f: 2*re(f.args[0]), 
                            lambda f: isinstance(f, Add) and len(f.args) == 2 and f.args[1] == f.args[0].conjugate())
g = g1.xreplace(fold_conjugates)
```

Final result: `4*pi*S*u*im(Vres*exp(2*I*pi*(l*u + m*v)))`.

Comment: That's really useful. I learned a number of things at once. Thanks.